# RSpec and rswag: How to perform enqueued jobs in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-activejob, rswag

I have an API project in Rails 5 using rswag for endpoint definition and testing.

One controller action, `create`, enqueues an ActiveJob with keyword arguments using `perform_later(job_title: @job, date: @date)`

When I use `run_test!` in my request spec for this action, I want to run the queued job immediately.

How do I force the job to run with the keyword arguments that were passed in the controller action?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `perform_enqueued_jobs` inside your `run_test!` block

```rb
run_test! do
  perform_enqueued_jobs
end
```